# Как в node.js узнать, сколько файлов в конкретной папке?

Tags: node.js

Собственно, есть путь к папке, нужно узнать, сколько в ней файлов .jpg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var files = fs.readdirSync(/imgs');
var jpgs = files.filter(function(el, i) {
  return el.substring(el.length - 3) == 'jpg';
});

console.log(jpgs.length);
```